# Chrome Extension Internals

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to understand the internals of Chrome Extension. It will be great if you can provide more details regarding this.

My understandings are as follows:

1. Extensions run in its own process.
2. Extensions interact with Browser process through IPC.

My question:
1. Whenever we call a extension api such as chrome.module.function() from extension user script, I would expect the function to go to the renderer process first and then send a IPC such as ExtensionHostMsg_ABC to the browser process to do the required operation.

```
                Extension Process                                  Browser Process

                                             ExtensionHostMsg_Req
               chrome.module.function()      ---------------->     Handle the msg

                                             ExtensionMsg_Response
                Send the result back to js   <-----------------
```

But to my surprise, I see that all the extension api functions are declared and defined in chrome/browser/extensions/xyz_api.h & .cc files. So it looks like when a api is called from js, we come directly to the browser process. Where and how does this magic happens?

1. I also see some extensions bindings c++ code in chrome/renderer/extensions/abc_bindings.cc and the corresponding js code in chrome/renderer/extensions/resources/abc.js. I think we have this code to share some information between the extension renderer and js code. Is it right? Can you provide me a example scenario for this?

Sorry for asking these basic questions. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question on how the bindings are made. You define your extension API in `chrome/common/extensions/api/extension_api.json` which is how V8 sets up the C++ JavaScript bindings. That is where all the magic happens :)

If you want to call privileged APIs from the content script you would need to add the namespace to `chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/renderer_extension_bindings.js`

For more information regarding the design of the Extension System in Chromium, there are good docs that explain the whole process model and interactions:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions